# Different fields for equals and hashcode

Tags: java, hashmap, equals, hashcode

I agree with the statement from this post [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

> Use the same set of fields that you use to compute equals() to compute hashCode().

But i've some doubts :

- Is this absolutely necessary to have same fields ?
- If yes, what if I don't use same field ?
- Will it affect HashMap performance or HashMap Accuracy ?

Comment: You should look at this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java`

Comment: @Hrish with that unnecessary formatting you prevented the link to be clickable.

Comment: well, sorry about that. I was thinking of putting it as an answer but it would actually answer the question so put it as a comment. let me modify it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals‌​-and-hashcode-methods-in-jav

Answer (score 3):

> Is this absolutely necessary to have same fields ?

Yes, if you don't want any surprises.

> If yes, what if I don't use same field ?

You might get different `hashCode` for objects that are equal, as per `equals()` method, which is a requirement for the equals and hashCode contract.

For example, suppose you've 3 fields - `a`, `b`, `c`. And you use `a` and `b` for `equals()` method, and all the 3 fields for `hashCode()` method. So, for 2 objects, if `a` and `b` are equals, and `c` is different, both will be equals with different hashcode.

> Will it affect HashMap performance or HashMap Accuracy ?

It's not about performance, but yes your map will not behave as expected.

Comment: Actually equals must be at least as specific as hashcode, so it's not that much if a problem if it's the other way around than in your example. Making hashcode more coarse at least does not break contracts and sematics. Therefore not having the same fields does not lead to surprises semantic wise. Of course I doubt it's usually a good idea to have them different.

Comment: @Drunix Yes in some cases it wouldn't really affect the semantics. Idea is, don't use fields in `hashCode` that is not there in `equals()`. But as you said, ideally we should use same fields to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 3):

The fields don't have to be the same.  The requirement is for two objects that are equal, they must have the same hash code.  If they have the same hash code, they don't have to be equal.  From the javadocs:

> - Whenever it is invoked on the same object more than once during an
>     execution of a Java application, the hashCode method must consistently
>     return the same integer, provided no information used in equals
>     comparisons on the object is modified. This integer need not remain
>     consistent from one execution of an application to another execution
>     of the same application.
> - If two objects are equal according to the
>     equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the
>     two objects must produce the same integer result.
> - It is not required
>     that if two objects are unequal according to the
>     equals(java.lang.Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on
>     each of the two objects must produce distinct integer results.
>     However, the programmer should be aware that producing distinct
>     integer results for unequal objects may improve the performance of
>     hash tables.

For example, you could return 1 as your hash code always, and you would obey the hash code contract, no matter what fields you used in your equals method.

Returning 1 all the time would improve the computation time of hashCode, but HashMap's performance would drop since it would have to resort to equals() more often.

Answer (score 0):

Fields used in hashcode can be a subset of fields used in equals.
It will still abide by this rule "Whenever a.equals(b), then a.hashCode() must be same as b.hashCode()"